# Migrating from Vite to Mix in Laravel Inertia App with breeze scaffolding (React) not Compiling

Tags: reactjs, laravel, webpack, inertiajs, laravel-breeze

I am scaffolding a new project using Laravel and Inertia Js with the breeze (react) scaffolding. The project is not compiling even after following the documentation on the official vite-plugin GitHub page at [Vite-plugin](https://github.com/laravel/vite-plugin/blob/main/UPGRADE.md)

Below is my webpack.mix.js file

```
const mix = require('laravel-mix');

mix
.setPublicPath('public')
.react()
.version()
.disableNotifications()
.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')
.postCss('resources/css/app.css', 'public/css', [
require('postcss-import'),
require('tailwindcss'),
require('autoprefixer'),
]); 

if (mix.inProduction()) {
mix.version();
}
```

And my app.jsx file

```
        require('./bootstrap');


    import { createRoot } from 'react-dom/client';
    import { createInertiaApp } from '@inertiajs/react';

    const appName = window.document.getElementsByTagName('title')[0]?.innerText || 'Applux';

    createInertiaApp({
        title: (title) => `${title} - ${appName}`,
        resolve: (name) => require(`./Pages/${name}`),
        setup({ el, App, props }) {
            const root = createRoot(el);
            root.render(<App {...props} />);
        },
        progress: {
            color: '#4B5563',
        },
    });
```

I really don't know where I am missing things. I have **webpack, laravel-mix, @inertiajs/react** installed on the project and my machine. I've read many sources but most of them use Vue Js scaffolding in their configurations instead of React JS.

When I run `npm run dev` on the project directory, I get this error:

```
ERROR in /js/app
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'C:\Users\Leonard\Dev\PHP\Laravel\projects\applux\resources\js\app.js' in 'C:\Users\Leonard\Dev\PHP\Laravel\projects\applux'
Did you miss the leading dot in 'resolve.extensions'? Did you mean '[".*",".wasm",".mjs",".js",".jsx",".json"]' instead of '["*",".wasm",".mjs",".js",".jsx",".json"]'?

webpack compiled with 1 error
```

I don't know what I am doing wrong. Please I need your support in resolving this error.
Thanks for your time.

Comment: Change `.js` to `.react` like this `mix.react('resources/js/app.jsx', 'public/js/app.js')` and try again.

Comment: I've tried that before and it resulted in a lot of duplicated errors almost for all the pages as far as I can remember.

Comment: In resources you're js file name is app.jsx whereas in mix config you're using app.js, try changing that

Comment: One question, why you're migrating from Vite to mix which is already deprecated?

Comment: Yeah...I changed the app.jsx to app.js and it worked. Thanks for the support.

Comment: Vite only replaced mix in scaffolding a new laravel project. Not all of laravel-mix package is deprecated but some features that it comes bundled with. It's still very much in use in some projects.